# How do I multiply a sequence with a non-int type of float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
cell = sheet['a1']
cell = sheet.cell(1, 1)

for row in range(1, sheet.max_row + 1):
    cell = sheet.cell(row, 3)
    corrected_price = cell.value * 0.9
    corrected_price_cell = sheet.cell(row, 4)
    corrected_price_cell.value = corrected_price

wb.save('transactions2.xlsx')
```

followed a tutorial online by mosh and did the exact same thing for automation with python and for some reason mine doesnt work on line 9 cause it says its a multiplication issue involving a float. heres the traceback

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/lukapavicic/Desktop/py/pythonProject/app.py", line 9, in 
corrected_price = cell.value * 0.9
~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the type of `cell.value` if it is a sequence like list, then you cannot mulitply it by float.
if it is a string you can probable use casting it to `float(cell.value)` or `int(cell.value)`